# Setting up a firewall to route between interfaces on a gateway

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, forwarding, gateway

I've been trying to setup a firewall on my debian gateway with iptables. The gateway is connected to a a network 12.120.0.0/24 on eth0 behind a NAT and the subnetwork behind it is 12.120.4.0/24 eth1. I've done much research and the most of the articles I read is setting up the gateway as a NAT and the rest just does not work for me. The gateway does not have to act as a NAT to the subnetwork because it can find every other computer on the network with ping and ssh if the firewall is flushed so forwarding between interfaces is working.

First of I would like that from inside the subnetwork on eth1 is ssh accepted from everyone to everyone but noone outside should be avalible to ssh inside the network and the eth0 interface on the gateway.

This is my sh file to first flush the firewall and apply the new rulesets

```
#Flush prevous rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z

#Default policies
iptables -P INPUT       DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT      DROP
iptables -P FORWARD     DROP

#Enable loopback
#iptables -A INPUT      -i lo -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT     -o lo -j ACCEPT

#Enable statefull rules
iptables -A INPUT       -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT      -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD     -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


#SSH

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT



iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

###LOGGING

iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 60/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

The command iptables -L -v gives the following output

```
root@gateway:~# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  801 99796 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 5331  853K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 5 packets, 200 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  688  122K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 7219 1989K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1175  125K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1378  105K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 LOGGING    all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Even tride with this file to test if I can instead enable ssh from outside to the subnetwork behind the gateway to see if that worked.

```
#Flush firewall rules and chains
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z

#Set policy table
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

#Rules
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

That should work but it doesn't let ssh traffic through.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks.

Comment: Is IP forwarding enabled? Post output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: Yes I have it enabled, the output is "1" and ip forwarding should work because it works when the iptable is flushed, I can connect both from outside to inside and vice versa with SSH/HTTP/HTTPS/SMTP/IMAP so the problem must lie in the rules I applied to iptables.